# Overloading operations and testing with GTest

Tags: c++, googletest

I not sure what it's wrong with my code. first of all I have a class with something like this.

```
class CHomaMessage{
private:
  const double id ;

  double prevIndex;

  const uint32_t size;
public:

  uint32_t remainingSize() const {
    return size - prevIndex;
  }

friend bool operator < (const CHomaMessage& lhs, const CHomaMessage& rhs);
friend bool operator > (const CHomaMessage& lhs, const CHomaMessage& rhs);
friend bool operator == (const CHomaMessage& lhs, const CHomaMessage& rhs);
}
```

and then also the implementation of that operators

```
#include "CHomaMessage.h"

bool operator <  (const CHomaMessage& lhs, const CHomaMessage& rhs){
  return lhs.remainingSize() < rhs.remainingSize();
}

bool operator >  (const CHomaMessage& lhs, const CHomaMessage& rhs){
  return lhs.remainingSize() > rhs.remainingSize();
}

bool operator == (const CHomaMessage &lhs, const CHomaMessage &rhs) {
  return lhs.remainingSize() == rhs.remainingSize();
}
```

So when I try to test this with the GTest looks like compare with the pointer itself and not with the remaining size function.

```
TEST_F(CHomaMessageTest, max_min_operators_overload ){
  CHomaMessage message2 = CHomaMessage(3, 0, 4, 1024);
  CHomaMessage message3 = CHomaMessage(2, 0, 4, 1024);

  //Try sending a reference (as is expected)
  EXPECT_TRUE(&message2 == &message3);

  //Try to send a object itself
  EXPECT_FALSE(message2 < message3);
}
```

My question it's about I'm not sure if Gtest cannot test the overload of the operators or I'm making something wrong (the last one its the most accurate option).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `&message2 == &message3` compares pointers, as you coded it. If you want to use your custom operator, it should be `message2 == message3` (or `EXPECT_EQ(message2, message3);`).

Comment: Also considered using `EXPECT_EQ(arg1, arg2)` instead of `EXPECT_TRUE(arg1 == arg2)` (and similarly `EXPECT_GE(arg1, arg2)` instead of `EXPECT_FALSE(arg1 < arg2)`).

Answer (score 0):

Your misconception is that `&obj` would be a reference to obj, while in reality it it a pointer.

Therefore this is comparing pointers and not references.

```
  // Comparing pointers
  EXPECT_TRUE(&message2 == &message3);
```

To get a reference of an object you can do this:

```
  CHomaMessage message2 = CHomaMessage(3, 0, 4, 1024);
  CHomaMessage message3 = CHomaMessage(2, 0, 4, 1024);
  const CHomaMessage& reference_to_message2 = message2;

  // reference points to the same address:
  EXPECT_EQ(&message2, &reference_to_message2);
  // message3 points to another address:
  EXPECT_NE(&message3, &reference_to_message2);

  // will use your operator
  EXPECT_EQ(message2, reference_to_message2);
  EXPECT_EQ(message2, message3);
  EXPECT_EQ(reference_to_message2, message3);
```